# Emissivity Relation Between viewing angle, wavelength and temperature

Tags: thermal-radiation

I am trying to find the relation between emissivity of a material, viewing angle(from normal) and temperature of a grey body. Is there a formula that gives us this relation. This is to create an emissivity map of a silicon wafer that is viewed from a certain angle and which is at a certain temperature. Any inputs is appreciated.